# ServiceStack and NHibernate Unit Of Work Pattern

Tags: nhibernate, servicestack, unit-of-work

Long story as brief as possible...

I have an existing application that I'm trying to get ServiceStack into to create our new API. This app is currently an MVC3 app and uses the UnitOfWork pattern using Attribute Injection on MVC routes to create/finalize a transaction where the attribute is applied.

Trying to accomplish something similar using ServiceStack

**[This gist](https://gist.github.com/4499951)**
 shows the relevant ServiceStack configuration settings. What I am curious about is the global request/response filters -- these will create a new unit of work for each request and close it before sending the response to the client (there is a check in there so if an error occurs writing to the db, we return an appropriate response to the client, and not a false "success" message)

My questions are:

1. Is this a good idea or not, or is there a better way to do
   this with ServiceStack.
2. In the MVC site we only create a new unit
   of work on an action that will add/update/delete data - should we do
   something similar here or is it fine to create a transaction only to retrieve data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [ServiceStack's IOC wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container) the Funq IOC registers dependencies as a singleton by default. So to register it with RequestScope you need to specify it as done here:

```
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<NHibernateUnitOfWork, IUnitOfWork()
    .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

Although this is not likely what you want as it registers as a singleton, i.e. the same instance returned for every request:

```
container.Register<ISession>((c) => {
    var uow = (INHibernateUnitOfWork) c.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
    return uow.Session;
});
```

You probably want to make this:

```
    .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request); //per request

    .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None); //Executed each time its injected
```

Using a `RequestScope` also works for Global Request/Response filters which will get the same instance as used in the Service.

Comment: Thanks! I guess what i'm hearing is "I'm good to create/commit the UOW in the request/response filters.

My NHibernateUnitOfWork is a singleton that uses the Session (injectedd) so as long as the session is setup to be request scoped (it is) the unit of work will be by proxy - but i guess it wouldn't hurt to add the reusedwithin(request).

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Whether you are using ServiceStack, MVC, WCF, Nancy, or any other web framework, the most common method to use is the session-per-request pattern. In web terms, this means creating a new unit of work in the beginning of the request and disposing of the unit of work at the end of the request. Almost all web frameworks have hooks for these events.

Resources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13206256/670028
- [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=servicestack+session+per+request](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=servicestack%20session%20per%20request)

**2)** You should always interact with NHibernate within a transaction.

Please see any of the following for an explanation of why:

- http://ayende.com/blog/3775/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged
- http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof/learn/alert/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions

Note that when switching to using transactions with reads, be sure to make yourself aware of NULL behavior: http://www.zvolkov.com/clog/2009/07/09/why-nhibernate-updates-db-on-commit-of-read-only-transaction/#comments

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the benefits of the Unit-Of-Work pattern and Session Per Request with NHibernate, I have that set up in my GIST that I linked. My question was more around if the way i'm starting and committing a transaction within a request was appropriate or not (using global request/response filters). I don't see any issues off-hand since I do have the session scoped to the request, but I was not sure of any trade offs that might occur...